# Logistic Regression with holdout sample

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am trying to run a logistic regression in R on my data where my independent variables are 13 continuous variables and my dependent variable is binary.  I want to segment my data so that I train on the first 80% and test on the last 20%.  I have a total of 3750 rows of data so I utilize the first 3000 for training.  I have written the following:

```
mydata<-totaldata[1:3000,2:15]
mylogit<-glm(mydata$TARGET ~ mydata$VAR1+mydata$VAR2+mydata$VAR3+mydata$VAR4+ #$
                             mydata$VAR5+mydata$VAR6+mydata$VAR7+mydata$VAR8+
                             mydata$VAR9+mydata$VAR10+mydata$VAR11+mydata$VAR12+
                             mydata$VAR13, family="binomial")

predictdata=totaldata[3001:3751,3:15]
in_frame<-data.frame(predictdata)
predictions=predict(mylogit,in_frame,type="response")
```

However I get the following warning message: 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 751 rows but variable(s) found have 3000 rows

Then when I look at predictions there are 3000 predictions not the 751 that I wanted.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you *only* want to know how to get R to do this? If so, your question is off-topic for CV (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)), but on-topic for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a substantive question about the statistical aspects here, please edit your Q to clarify this; if not, flag it & we'll migrate it for you. (*Please don't cross-post, though*, SE explicitly discourages this.)

Comment: A couple of additional notes: You can just list your variables in the formula as `VAR1+VAR2...`, and then include a `data=mydata` argument. This approach might be easier for you. Also, the selected columns of `mydata` & `predictdata` differ (**2**:15, & **3**:15). I suspect this is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises from the fact you have specified the formula

```
mydata$TARGET ~ mydata$VAR1+mydata$VAR2+mydata$VAR3+mydata$VAR4+ #$
                         mydata$VAR5+mydata$VAR6+mydata$VAR7+mydata$VAR8+
                         mydata$VAR9+mydata$VAR10+mydata$VAR11+mydata$VAR12+
                         mydata$VAR13
```

This means, when you run predict, it is looking for variables with names like

`` `mydata$Var1` ``

This causes scoping issues as it will look for the column `` `mydata$Var1` `` within your newdata object (which don't exist), and eventually evaulate to `mydata$Var1` (hence the warning as it has found the the object with length 3000 which conflicts with the size of newdata`.

In essence you have forced `predict.glm` to ignore the data in the `newdata` argument.

If you specify the formula in call to `glm`

```
mylogit<-glm(TARGET ~ VAR1 + VAR2 + VAR3 + VAR4 + VAR5 + VAR6 + VAR7 + VAR8 + 
   VAR9 + VAR10 + VAR11 + VAR12 + VAR13, family="binomial", data = mydata)
```

Then all should be well.